# Getting Text String from EditText and transfer it to compose message

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-4.3-jelly-bean

How can I transfer a text from EditText input to compose message. Say for example:

Enter phone number: 
2366
Enter message:
MUSIC ON

and it will generate automatically in Compose Message

To: 2366

Message: MUSIC ON

Comment: What do you mean "compose message"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your own:

You have 2 EditTexts as,

```
EditText ed_to;
EditText ed_message;
```

Before using following code, initialize EditTexts using findViewById()

```
String to=ed_to.getText.toString();
String message=ed_message.getText.toString();
 SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(to, null, message, null, null);
```

Update: While using above code, you have to set permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

This will not show you the compose message window, instead, directly send sms.

If you don't want to set permission and want to see compose message, use following:

```
String to=ed_to.getText().toString();
                String msg=ed_message.getText().toString();
                Intent smsIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms"); 
                smsIntent.putExtra("address", to);
                smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body",msg);
                startActivity(smsIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks. By the way, If I chose the first way where in I didn't want to see compose message, rather send it directly, how will I know if the message was sent? Or how can I place a message indicating it was sent?

Should I placed it after:

`sms.sendTextMessage(to, null, message, null, null);`

Comment: Look at answer by David. Using those PendingIntents is preferable `sms.sendTextMessage(to, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI)`, if you really want to monitor. Else, just give a Toast after it.

Answer (score 1):

You do it this its simple one...

```
Intent intentSendMessage= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intentSendMessage.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
smsIntent.putExtra("address", "12125551212");
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body","Body of Message");
startActivity(intentSendMessage);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want exactly

```
 final Button buttonLaunchSMS= (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonLaunchSMSMessage);
    buttonLaunchSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String outCipherText= editTextSMSCipherText.getText().toString();
            String phoneNumber= editTextPhoneNumber.getText().toString();

            // pre-conditions
            if (outCipherText.length() < 1){
                editTextSMSCipherText.setError("Cipher Text is Empty");
                editTextSMSCipherText.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            if (outCipherText.length()>MAX_SMS_CHAR){
                editTextSMSCipherText.setError("Error. Message Is Too Large.");
                editTextSMSCipherText.requestFocus();
                return;
            }

            String uri= "smsto:"+phoneNumber;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(uri));
            intent.putExtra("sms_body", outCipherText);
            intent.putExtra("compose_mode", true);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to inicializate a variable, lets say String phone, and get the object editTex of phone by using the findViewById("phoneEditText"); then the string phone would have the value you want